# Arachni on VPS. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on connect with WebUI

Tags: web-application

After starting arachni on VPS, I'm trying to connect with web UI. But browser cannot establish connection with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
Some console output:
**arachni**

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.6.4 (ruby 2.7.5-p203) ("Birdie's Version")
*  Min threads: 0
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 380696
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:9292
* Listening on http://[::1]:9292
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

**ufw:**

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8000                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9292                       ALLOW IN    my.ip.here.51
80                         ALLOW IN    my.ip.here.51
443                        ALLOW IN    my.ip.here.51
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

What I did wrong?

P.S. Apache default welcome page is visible for me

Comment: This looks like a network troubleshooting question, and as such needs a lot more information. Like where you are connecting from, how you are connecting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're listening only on localhost, try binding to a different address, 0.0.0.0 or the one of the WAN interface.